# File comparison utility

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am looking for compare utility similar for "win merge" or "beyond compare" .
That in addition for gui comparison will have api that i will be able to run  on my files via my code and see if the files are the same or not and also use it in gui mode to show graphically the differences .

Any recommendations ?

thanks

Comment: linky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

Comment: use a debugger like softice...to visualize program & code simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kdiff might do what you need.
[Kdiff command line](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html#commandline)

Comment: kdiff3 is simply amazing! In particular - and I know this is a bit off topic - I like the fact that if a single character changed on a line, it will highlight that character. Most diff tools will highlight the entire line, making it a real pain to identify the actual change.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a Diff API (as opposed to a standalone tool), try [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) - it's a two-way or three-way diff utility, it can handle ANSI, ASCII and Unicode files (it can even compare an ANSI file to a Unicode file!), and it offers both a command-line interface, as well as an [automation API](http://www.araxis.com/merge/automation_ref.html) for including its smarts into your own apps.

Highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention free or not.  If free, Sourcegear's DiffMerge: http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I like [ExamDiff Pro](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiffpro.asp).  There is also a [no cost version](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 3 does support command line actions, so you should be able to hook it into any existing process that you have.

Here's the command line documentation, if you're interested:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/help/index.html?command_line_reference.html

Free versions are available for download.

Answer (score 0):

WinMerge IS open source, you could modify it to do what you want (even though I am pretty sure it does have command line access and an API you could use).